# Theorem** on page 288 from Geometry of algebraic curves by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, Harris

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOwja.png)Let $V$ a $2n$ complex vector space and take on $V$ a quadratic form.
Now define $$ \Sigma=\{\Lambda:Q(\Lambda,\Lambda)\equiv0 \} \subset Gr(n,2n)$$ where $\Lambda$ is a maximal subspace i.e it is not contained in other isotropics subspaces
Show that:

1. $\Sigma$ is a smooth complex variety of dimension $n(n-1)/2$,
2. $\Sigma$ has exactly two conected components $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$,
3. if $\Lambda \in \Sigma_i$ and $\Lambda^{'} \in \Sigma_j$ are two maximal isotropic subspace for $Q$ than $$dim(\Lambda \cap \Lambda^{'}) \equiv n \quad mod(2) \Leftrightarrow i=j$$.
   On the book the authors say that thees facts are standard and put as references Griffiths Harris, Principles of algebraic surfaces, proposition on page 735. I've seen it but i'm so confused about how to use it. Can someone help me how does it work? 
   [image: definition of quadric]
   [image: proposition]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try the $n=2$ case first, you'll quickly see that all the others are nearly the same.

When $n=2$ we have a four-dimensional vector space, say
$$V = \operatorname{span}\{e_0, e_1, e_2, e_3\}.$$
Since every nondegenerate quadratic form on a vector space (in characteristic $\neq 2$) is equivalent to every other, we can just pick a quadratic form and examine it.  So take
$$Q(x, y) := x_0 y_3 + x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1 + x_3 y_0.$$
where
$$x = \sum_{i=0}^3 x_i e_i, \qquad y = \sum_{j=0}^3 y_j e_j.$$

Suppose we have some $\Lambda \in Gr(2, V)$.  Notice that a two-dimensional subspace of $V$ is the same thing as a line in $\mathbb{P}V$.  I claim that $Q(\Lambda, \Lambda) = 0$ if, and only if, the line $\mathbb{P}\Lambda \subset \mathbb{P}V$ lies on the surface
$$S = \mathbb{P}(\{v \in V\; | \; Q(v,v) = 0\}) = V(2 x_0 x_3 + 2 x_1 x_2) \subset \mathbb{P}V.$$

To see this, suppose first that $Q(\Lambda, \Lambda) = 0$.  Then for any $v \in \Lambda$, $Q(v,v) = 0$, so $[v] \in S$.  Conversely, suppose $\mathbb{P}\Lambda \subset S$.  Let $\Lambda$ be spanned by $v, w \in V$.  Then $[v], [w] \in S$, so $Q(v,v) = Q(w,w) = 0$.   Further, $[v+w] \in S$, so
$$0 = Q(v+w, v+w) = Q(v,v) + 2 Q(v,w) + Q(w,w) = 2 Q(v,w),$$
i.e. $Q(v,w) = 0$.  Therefore $Q(\Lambda, \Lambda) = 0.$

Now the remaining statements come down to the fact that $S$ is a surface with two different rulings, which are easy to exhibit directly from the equation
$$x_0 x_3 + x_1 x_2 = 0$$
above.  The third point, which is probably the most confusingly phrased, says in this case that:

- Two lines on the same ruling do not intersect, and
- Two lines on opposite rulings intersect in a point.

That statement gets a *little* more subtle in higher dimensions, but the idea is still about the same.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by ruling? you mean that the surface is ruled

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: there is something that is not clear. You take $n=2$ so the variety $\Sigma$ must have dimension $n(n-1)/2=1$. in your example what is the dimension of $\Sigma$? I'm confused because $\Sigma $ is the set of all $\Lambda$.

Comment: In this case, $\Sigma$ is the set of all lines on the quadric.  Each ruling is a one-dimensional family of lines, so $\Sigma$ consists of two disjoint one-dimensional components.  (In fact, each component is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.)

Comment: So can i say that its dimension is $1$? And when you write $V(2x_0 x_3+2x_1 x_2)$ do you mean the subspace of $V$ generated by the vectors that satisfy the condition in brackets?

Comment: It's the projective variety cut out of $\mathbb{P}V$ by the equation $x_0 x_3 + x_1 x_2 = 0$.  Are you clear on how projective space works?

Comment: i'm thinking at $\Sigma $ as a subvariety of $\mathbb{P} (V)$. So as subvariety of this projective space has dimension $1$. If i take local coordinates on the projective space, i should find a local chart that map a neighborhood of a point to $\mathbb{C}^1$.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a subvariety of Gr(2, V), not of $\mathbb{P}V$.

Comment: yes but i can embed the grassmannian in the projective space an so i get a subvariey of some projective space.  I think that the problem is that in the statement the author doesn't say if the dimension of $\Sigma $ as subvariety of the grassmannian or as subvariety of the grassmannian embedded in a projective space. But i think that this dimension could be the same via embedding?

Comment: so my variety must have dimension 1 as subvariety of the Grassmannian and must have dimension 1 if i embeds it in the projective space via the plucker application

Comment: Dimension is an intrinsic property of a variety, so $\Sigma$ will be one-dimensional no matter what it's embedded in.  Moreover, the Grassmannian $Gr(2,4)$, which is four-dimensional, doesn't embed into $\mathbb{P}V \cong \mathbb{P}^3$, it embeds into $\mathbb{P}(V \wedge V) \cong \mathbb{P}^5$.

Comment: ok now is clear. So when you write $S=....=V(.......)$ i can write $x \in \mathbb{P}^3: x_0 x_3+x_1 x_2=0$

Comment: If the quadric form is simmetric i can write $Q(x,x)=x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ due to the sylvester theorem, right? if i can use this quadric computation will be more simple in high dimensional case

Comment: Yes, all nondegenerate quadric forms are equivalent.